# Javascript object not updating on time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JS Object

I tried to assign a property

```
onDeskEquipmentData[EQParasite.id].contentInformation.contentwise[I].thermos = {thermoProp: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thermos_data["compound"])),};
```

*note:- variable `I` is from `forEach(function(I){})` loop it iterates inside a array;*

It do not assign `thermos` property on time as in the next line a function named `updateTempratureOnShare(EQHost)` uses the thermos property throws an error that it don't contain the thermos property. I used `console.log()` to confirm this and yes it didn't contain that but when I manually checked on my browser's console for `onDeskEquipmentData[EQParasite.id].contentInformation.contentwise[I].thermos` It was there, I have also used settimeout but it didn't work. This error is comming in some more places.

*note:- function `updateTempratureOnShare(EQHost)` is not inside forEach loop*

Comment: The description implies that there's something more happening here, something you're not realizing and thus not describing.  Which is why it's far more constructive to have a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, rather than just describing what you think the code you're not showing us should be doing.  Please update the question to a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem, replacing external operations with hard-coded results as needed to isolate the problem.

Comment: @David I just check the code and realise that the object is more than 15KBs which is why JS is pushing changes into buffer not changing it at the moment.